# Would structural colouring work for making hair green, blue and or grey?

Tags: biology

Today I was thinking about how to make an elf who naturally grows blue hair. Thinking about this I came up with the idea of coloring the hair using microscopic eyes like with blue, green and gray eyes for normal people. I am wondering what would be required for this to work and what would be required to make darker shades, and the color purple, in elven hair. Now the fact that they are elves isn't very important; their biology is actually fairly similar except for in some places, so you can pretend their basically human for now.

Comment: Related: [Can you help me design humans that naturally grow green hair?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/14597/32451)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me design humans that naturally grow green hair?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14597/can-you-help-me-design-humans-that-naturally-grow-green-hair)

Comment: I would suggest researching how bird feathers are so colourful.

Comment: *Some* mammals do use structural coloration to obtain unusual skin colors, for example the [blue faces of the mandrills](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mathiasappel/24921031530). Structural coloring of fur is much more rare -- for example, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Structural_coloration&oldid=867530863) that the Cape golden mole exhibits structural fur coloration. The cortex of a strand of human is composed of relatively well-structured (bodies of dead) rod-like cells, so structural coloration may be possible; but I won't say that it definitely *is* possible.

Comment: Works for e.g. peafowl & butterflies, so why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your elves can grow hair with nano-grooves with needed size, you could have different colors.[image]

Or use new pigments. [Colors in nature post.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/in-pictures-36674573)

We have grey, silver to white hair just by producing less or no pigments(melanin) in hair follicles. It is same as we get older some pigment cells die = less melanin.

Comment: The problem with having Grey, silver and white hair by producing less pigiments is that it makes their skin extremely white to

Comment: No, it is same how you get grey&white hair from old age. You for sure do not get pale skin from that.