# Could there be a humanoid species with blue or multicolored hair?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

So i was wondering why dogs and cats for example have a way bigger color variety than humans have when it comes to hair color. Why are dogs and cats so often multicolored, with spots or stripes, while humans are not? I am aware of things like vitiligo, but that´s nowhere near as common as multicolored dogs or cats! Why? Also, blue hair. Not anime blue but the blue-ish gray you find in cats and other animals.

Would it in any way be possible to have a humanoid species have that same color variation, with spotted or striped skin or multicolored or blue hair?

Comment: Related: [Human hair color boundary?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/44371/32451), [Would structural colouring work for making hair green, blue and or grey?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/130788/32451)

Comment: Human can have [white patches of hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliosis) on their heads. Mammals don't produce blue pigments. And humans do occasionally have patches of hair of different colors on their heads; search for [heterochromia of the scalp hair](https://www.google.com/search?q=heterochromia+of+the+scalp+hair). (In fact, in men it is not at all uncommon to have hair of one color on the head, and of a different color in the beard or eyebrows.)

Comment: Or even more recently, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186811/are-other-colors-of-fur-plausible Mostly people have a lot less hair, so it's less critical. There probably would be more colorful sapients if there were more sapients - differentiation would be more critical. Most mammals are brown, yellow, red & shades in between because most mammals don't see color that well. Contrast in patterns is more critical.

Comment: With respect, this might not be precise enough for this blog. We don't have much hair variety simply because our primate ancestors don'

Comment: Are you using humanoid to mean human-shaped or human-related, i.e. hominid?

Comment: Cats can be blue though, so why not humans? 
But would it be POSSIBLE to get humanoids with blue hair? Also, i mean human-shaped.

Comment: @AlexP, I actually have a huge variety of hair color in my beard, but it's scattered by individual hairs. I see blonde, black, various browns, red, white, and probably a few other standard colors when I shave.

Comment: If the Q I used to VTC:duplicate isn't considered a duplicate enough, [try this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/89709/40609). I'd need some serious convincing to believe that changing the color from green to blue makes this question unique.

Comment: @JBH one difference is that mammals can have blue fur but not green?

Comment: @JBH also no i´m not looking for a medical condition, i´m looking for natural causes for a species to be born with and have this color.

Comment: @Wildschwein natural causes = medical condition, but as I said, the alternative answer is the duplicate if the one I proposed doesn't work. I don't believe blue-vs-green is a unique enough differentiator to justify two questions. Since humans have neither blue nor green hair, there must obviously be a physiological modification to get humanoids with either.